# Deleting a value in a column in Laravel using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I would need to delete a value in a column in the `Grpusr` table. The below code would select the whole row and delete it, but how do I delete the value in the `group_id` column only?

```
$grpusrdel = Grpusr::find($grpusrid);
$grpusrdel->delete();
```

Comment: Set it to null?

Comment: no, it has a value, and I will delete it after a certain action.

Comment: Setting it to null is the same as deleting the value.

Comment: What do you mean by `delete`? You can't delete a column without deleting the entire column of that table - to "delete" the column of a row, you set the value to something else - what is it? Zero, `null`, an empty string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$grpusrdel = Grpusr::find($grpusrid);

// Make sure you've got the model
if($grpusrdel) {
    $grpusrdel->group_id = null;
    $grpusrdel->save();
}
```